# How to remove only entirely duplicate values from an array?

Tags: php

I have a website where my database is set up with different artists and song titles within the same row, where it might look this:

```
artist: The Monkees, title: I'm A Believer
artist: The Monkees, title: Daydream Believer
artist: The Hollies, title: The Air That I Breathe
artist: The Hollies, title: Bus Stop
artist: The Beatles, title: Hello, Goodbye
artist: The Beatles, title: Yellow Submarine
```

And I have an autocomplete widget set up with my site's search form that is fed a json_encoded array filled with 'artist' values.

The first problem is that if a user were to begin typing "the" into the search form, values would come up like this:

**The Monkees

The Monkees

The Hollies

The Hollies

The Beatles

The Beatles**

So I used the array_unique function to remove duplicate values, but it seems that even if a value has one duplicate word (this case being "the"), it is removed entirely, so only the first value is returned:

**The Monkees**

Where the output I would like to have would be:

**The Monkees

The Hollies

The Beatles**

So, what might be another way I can remove these duplicate values and display them the way I would like?

EDIT:

Here is my source code:

```
<?php

include 'includes/config.php';

$return_arr = array();
$term = ($_GET['term']);

if ($con)
{
$artist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE artist LIKE '%$term%' LIMIT 0, 5");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($artist, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

$row_array['value'] = strtolower($row['artist']);

array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
  }
}

mysql_close($con);

echo json_encode(array_unique($return_arr));
?>
```

Comment: What about just filtering them out in the SQL query using `GROUP`?

Comment: Your intuition is wrong, the bug is not in array_unique.  Show us some code.

Comment: Added my source. Actually I know it's not a bug, I think it's just the way array_unique works? I don't understand it entirely. So I'm looking for some explanation and maybe a solution.

Comment: deceze, I just tried using group and it worked fantastically! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @socro Since you're using LIMIT in your query, this may after all not be exactly what you want, since it will first LIMIT, then GROUP (i.e. you may get less results than you could). Search for or make a new question about how to filter duplicates while using LIMIT. First and foremost though, data filtering is specifically the job of the database, don't do it manually when the database can do it for you!

Comment: Good advice, I'll remember that from now on!

Answer (score 2):

`array_unique` uses a strict comparison.  So differences in case and whitespace are taken into consideration.  Since all of those values seem to be strings, it's likely the reason why `array_unique` is not working the way you would expect.

Your database structure makes it pretty difficult to weed out duplicates.  I would suggest refactoring it into a table of artists and a table of songs, where songs simply reference the id of artist.  This will give you a better chance of being able to keep your artist list unique.

Also, one thing I would do for your autocomplete is set it up to ignore certain strings. ('a', 'an', 'the')  These are known as stopwords, and help search results be more relevant by not performing a search on common words.

Comment: The best idea is indeed re-factoring your database.  Your single-column blob will make any other solution pretty painful.